# Owner drawn groupbox and the RDP

Tags: .net, winforms, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a, hopefully, simple question. If I extend GroupBox control and in OnPaint event I create a gradient background instead of a default border what would that mean in terms of RDP performance considering that most Forms will have several groupboxes?

Answer (score 1):

I have worked on a Windows Forms application delivered over RDP that had many subtle background gradients, and its performance over RDP was quite acceptable. You'd have to test the performance of your particular gradient rendering method in your environment. I'm not sure whether RDP's GDI+ client rendering handles gradients.